# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore Notification for Current Device

Tags: icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to store user preferences in iCloud. To ensure that I understand how `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` works, I successfully stored a `String` value and monitored the value on a separate device. The following explains my configuration.

I started by observing the `Notification` that is posted when the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` changes externally:

```swift
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification
```

Then, I set a `String` value that was input of a `UITextField`:

```swift
let store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default
store.set(text, forKey: key)
store.synchronize()
```

To ensure that this works, I created a `UIAlertController` in the method that responds to the notification. I observed the alert appear on the secondary device within six seconds of setting the value on the primary device. However, I never observed the alert appear on the primary device after setting the value.

After reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore) for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, I was unable to find a reason that the primary device would not also receive the notification after updating the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`.

Do I need a solution to save the updated values locally before setting them in the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`? I can persist the values locally in `UserDefaults` before persisting them in `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. However, it would require me to revert the values in `UserDefaults` if an error should occur during the attempt to persist them in the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. Without the primary device being notified of the changes that are persisted from it, will I even be notified of the error in the observation of the notification? I struggle to believe that I will if I am not receiving notifications when successful.

Is there something that I am missing, or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @ShadeToD I did not find a solution. It has been nearly five years since I last interacted with `NSUbituitousKeyValueStore`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps they [updated the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore/1412267-didchangeexternallynotification) (+ 1 yr since you asked).

> "This notification is sent only upon a change received from iCloud; it is not sent when your app sets a value."

I assume that means that because no change is observed (the local device and iCloud are already in sync) - you don't get a notification.